# I am trying to display the file name as FileName_date in php

Tags: php

I want out put as: `FileName_Date`

I am using this code

```
$course_name=$_SESSION["course_Name"];

$time = date("d-m-Y")."-".time() ;
$course_name = $course_name."-".$time ;
```

after using this code i am getting out_put with only `FileName`

thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using `date("YmdHis")` for naming filenames with dates. Using this convention will keep the files sortable on date when browsing the directory in case the 'created_at'/'edited_at' dates aren't useable. So start with the largest "unit" and work down to the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....
get datetime for using date("d-m-Y H:s:a")

```
$course_name="test";

$time = date("d-m-Y H:s:a");
echo $course_name = $course_name."-".$time ;
```

It return "test-12-06-2015 08:17:am"

Comment: But the file name is not static its dynamic. i trying to copy the file value from another PHP file. in this case what should i do ?

Comment: If i use  $course_name = $time."-".$course_name ; it giving correct out-put as : Time_FileName.if i interchange the Variables it not showing time giving only file name... after this code i am trying to display the file name. i have used the below code to display the file header.                                                                            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$course_name);

Comment: Try this..<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["course_Name"]="test";
$course_name=$_SESSION["course_Name"];

$time = date("d-m-Y H:s:a");
echo $test  = $course_name."-".$time ;
echo "</br>";
echo $test = $time."-".$course_name ;
?>